# Passing Object as a props and using map() function on it in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, frontend

When I pass the object data as props to the component and looping through the data using the `map()` function I get the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`.

```js
import React from 'react'
import styles from './social.module.css';
import {Button, Typography, CardContent, CardActions, Card} from '@material-ui/core'
const SocialItem = ({
    Icon,
    title,
    mixed,
    red,
    blue,
    item
}) => {
    return (
        <Card className={styles.socialItem}>
            <CardContent>
                <Typography className={styles.socialItem__typo} variant="h4" component="h2">{title}</Typography>
                <Icon
                    className={`${styles.socialItem__Logo} ${mixed && styles.mixedInsta} ${blue && styles.blueFacebook} ${red && styles.redInsta}`}/>
                <div className={styles.desc}>
                    {item.map(itm => <li>{itm.price}</li>)}
                </div>
            </CardContent>
            <CardActions className=""></CardActions>
        </Card>
    )
}

export default SocialItem
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't seen how the "item" looks like and supposing it's an actual array, you can try add this:

```
{item !== undefined && item.map(itm => <li>{itm.price}</li>)}
```

If this doesn't work check what you pass to the component as the "item" prop.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked by checking the condition for undefined.

Comment: For shorter syntax, you can do `!!item && item.map...` as well.